# Keep new step of checkout fields value after refresh the page in magento 2.4.x

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have a question on how to keep the filled value of the new step checkout fields in Magento.

1. I create a new step as the instruction:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html. Here is my js for the new step (My_Checkoutfield/js/view/product-service-step)

> define([
> "ko",
> "jquery",
> "Magento_Ui/js/form/form",
> "underscore",
> "Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator",
> "Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list",
> ], function (ko, $, Component, _, stepNavigator, addressList) {
> "use strict";

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: "My_Checkoutfield/checkout-service-info",
    },
    isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
    isVisible: ko.observable(true),
    stepCode: "detailOfService",
    stepTitle: "Service Detail",
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        stepNavigator.registerStep(
            this.stepCode,
            null,
            this.stepTitle,
            this.isVisible,
            _.bind(this.navigate, this),
            15
        );
        return this;
    },
    navigate: function () {
        this.isVisible(true);
    },
    navigateToNextStep: function () {
        if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    },
    validateShippingInformation: function () {
        if (this.isFormInline) {
            this.source.set("params.invalid", false);
            this.source.trigger("serviceInfo.data.validate");
            if (this.source.get("params.invalid")) {
                this.focusInvalid();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
});
```

});

checkout_index_index.xml

[image]

checkout-service-info.html

```
<li
id="detailOfService"
data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }"
class="checkout-shipping-address">

<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>
<div
    id="checkout-step-shipping"
    class="step-content pivotel-service-plan"
    data-role="content"
>
    <form
        class="form form-shipping-address"
        id="co-shipping-form"
        novalidate="novalidate"
        data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep"
        data-hasrequired="* Required Fields"
        data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
    >
        <fieldset id="shipping-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar" style="margin-top: 3rem">
            <div class="primary">
                <button
                    data-role="opc-continue"
                    type="submit"
                    class="button action continue primary"
                    id="pivotel-service-step"
                >
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</li>
```

LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
 $shippingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['info-for-service']['children']['info-for-service-fieldset']['children'];
```

All the new fields of the new step are like:

```
$shippingConfiguration[$customAttributeRegIDCode] = $this->processCustomerRegisterId($dataScopePrefix, $customAttributeRegIDCode);
```

The fields of the new step of checkout work very well other than the fields of the new step won't keep the fills after refreshing the page. I skip some code to save field data to quote and order.

Comment: I tried but did not figure out how Magento populate the filled value of the checkout field back to the form after refresh

Comment: hi @jun were you able to figure out how magento populate the filled value of field after refresh ?

Comment: @AsharRiaz I tried as much as I can but don't know how to deal with it